# How to use the Repeat After Me application in Mac OS developer tools

Tags: macos, voice

In `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Speech`
any idea?

Comment: How do you find this app in modern times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeat After Me is an application that allows for the recording of one's own voice along side the TTS technology built into OS X. The software graphs both your voice and the TTS([Text-to-speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-to-speech)) voice and allows for imposing the pitch of your voice to that of the computer TTS voice, thus allowing an attempt of a more humanized infliction upon the TTS audio.

Tests the operating system's phonemic translation engine, creates graphs of the generated tone, to visually adjust the intonation, and records samples for reference.

You can read about it more from its Documentation.

[image]

from the Documentation..

> 1.Type in source text.
>
> 2.Convert the source text to phonemes and "tune" representation (with
>   information of phoneme
>   pitch/duration).
>
> 3.Record with a microphone or load from a sound file a voice
>   representation of the entered text.
>
> 4.Extract pitch and duration information from the recorded voice
>   (or imported file).
>
> 5.Apply the recorded pitch and duration to source phonemes.
>   6.    Interactively edit pitch/duration representation.
>
> 7.Obtain pitch/duration phonemes representation in text form for
>   further use with the Text-To-Speech
>   component.